# How Hogwarts' teachers find where Muggle-born witches and wizards live?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

I've read this in [The Quill of Acceptance and the Book of Admittance](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-quill-of-acceptance-and-the-book-of-admittance) on Pottermore, and the answers in: [How and when did Hermione find out she's a witch?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59999/how-and-when-did-hermione-find-out-shes-a-witch).

We know that a member of Hogwarts' staff goes and explains to the Muggle-born that they're wizards or witches. But how do they track them? For wizards families they simply send an owl, but for Muggle-borns, how exactly do they find a specific location that a Muggle-born resides.

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate. I need to find that question.

Comment: @CreationEdge im VTC, this is answered a few different times on this site.