# how to find Muggleborn Wizards?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, muggles

How, in the Harry Potter books, do the wizards find Muggleborns who are wizards and ready for Hogwarts? 
Someone like Hermoine can not "just" enroll in Hogwarts I think.
Who found her and introduced her, and her parents, to the wizardworld?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Hogwarts Headmaster know whom to invite to school?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10433/how-does-the-hogwarts-headmaster-know-whom-to-invite-to-school)

Comment: Better duplicate: [How and when did Hermione find out she's a witch?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/59999/98028) which tackles 1/ the magical quill and 2/ that a wizard comes to explain stuff to the muggleborns

Comment: try with magic.

Comment: Google them . . . Hermione's on google, ofc

Answer (score 0):

## Their magic is found by a Hogwarts quill.

At Hogwarts, there is a book and a quill which detect magic in children, and each child in Britain who shows signs of magic is given a place in Hogwarts should they choose to accept it. This quill detects the magic in Muggleborns as well.

> How can two Muggles have a kid with magical powers? Also how does the Ministry of Magic find out these kids have powers?
>
> A. It's the same as two black-haired people producing a redheaded child. Sometimes these things just happen, and no one really knows why! The Ministry of Magic doesn't find out which children are magic. In Hogwarts there's a magical quill which detects the birth of a magical child, and writes his or her name down in a large parchment book. Every year Professor McGonagall checks the book, and sends owls to the people who are turning 11. 
> <sub><sup>*[- JKR interview with scholastic.com (February 3, 2000)](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0200-scholastic-chat.htm)*</sup></sub>

The quill and book are the only selection process used for Hogwarts students. Once a child is found to be magical, they are allowed to attend.

> Beside the book, which is bound in peeling black dragon-hide, stands a small silver inkpot and from this protrudes a long, faded quill.  These are the Quill of Acceptance and the Book of Admittance and they constitute the only process by which students are selected for Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry.
>
> If anybody understands what powerful and long-lasting magic causes this book and quill to behave as they do, nobody has ever confessed to it, doubtless because (as Albus Dumbledore once sighed) it saves the staff tedious explanations to parents who are furious that their children have not been selected for Hogwarts. The Book and Quill’s decision is final and no child has ever been admitted whose name has not first been inscribed on the book’s yellowing pages.
>
> At the precise moment that a child first exhibits signs of magic, the Quill, which is believed to have been taken from an Augurey, floats up out of its inkpot and attempts to inscribe the name of that child upon the pages of the Book (Augurey feathers are known to repel ink and the inkpot is empty; nobody has ever managed to analyse precisely what the silvery fluid flowing from the enchanted Quill is). 
> <sub><sup>*[- The Quill of Acceptance and The Book of Admittance (wizardingworld.com)](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-quill-of-acceptance-and-the-book-of-admittance)*</sup></sub>

Muggleborns, along with children born to families with magical parents, get Hogwarts letters because their names are marked down in the book by the quill.

## Hogwarts informs their parents of magic.

When Snape tells Lily about Hogwarts letters, he says that for Muggleborns, someone from Hogwarts comes to explain everything to their parents.

> “And will it really come by owl?’ Lily whispered.
>
> ‘Normally,’ said Snape. ‘But you’re Muggle-born, so someone from the school will have to come and explain to your parents.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 33 (The Prince’s Tale)*</sup></sub>

So, when Muggleborns reach the age where they will be able to attend Hogwarts soon, someone from Hogwarts explains magic to their family first.

Comment: This is a gazillionth duplicate. Better to vote to close than providing yet a new redundant answer.